# How to merge dataframes with others that have empty column values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Have tried to merge DF1 and DF2 but cannot success. Please help. I used the code
DF_new = DF1.merge(DF2[["C", "Z"]], on="C", how="left")

[image]

Comment: what is the output or the error you are getting?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Is column 'Z' a column of undefined values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying with should work

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "B":[4,5,6], "C":[7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"C":[7,8,9]})
df2["Z"] = ""

df3 = df1.merge(right=df2[["C","Z"]], on="C", how="left")

   A  B  C Z
0  1  4  7  
1  2  5  8  
2  3  6  9
```